# R: Convert/Read 3D Matrix into a 'magick' object and vice versa

Tags: r, imagemagick, rmagick, magick-r-package

I want to work with the `magick` package for its fantastic image manipulations capabilities. Looking through [here](https://ropensci.org/tutorials/magick_tutorial/) I can't seem to find out how to convert a 3D matrix (width x height x channels) to a `magick` object I can further manipulate, and vice versa.

- There is no `as.magick` function
- The `as.matrix` function does not work

But I would like something like:

```
height <- 100
width <- 80
X <- array(runif(height * width * 3, min = 0, max = 255), c(height, width, 3))

magick::as.magick(X) %>% magick::image_scale("500x400")
```

(Obviously I could write the matrix to disk as an image, then read it with `magick::image_read`, that would be an overkill)

What did I miss?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `image_read()` to read a matrix as well. However note that the convention is to scale the values between 0 and 1 in case of doubles. So you need to divide your `X` by 255. Try this:

```
img <- magick::image_read(X / 255) %>% magick::image_scale("500x400")
```

If you want to convert the magick object back to an array:

```
image_data(img, 'rgba')
```

Or just `img[[1]]` works as well.

Comment: O. M. G. Thanks!

Comment: This conversion from magick to a numeric 3D matrix does not work any more with the code from this answer as far as I can tell because magick stores the pixel values as hexadecimals (from 00 to ff) instead of decimals.

Comment: @droplet yes it does, R just shows raw data in hex notation when you print it to the terminal. You probably want to use `as.integer(img[[1]])` if you don't understand how to use raw vectors.

Comment: @Jeroen thanks. I would like to ask a follow-up question. After`as.integer(img[[1]])`, I further make it a data.frame by `img[[1]] %>% as.integer %>% melt %>% dcast(Var1+Var2~Var3, value.var="value)`. After I'd done the manipulation of the data, how can I reassemble it back to magick object?

Comment: @Jeroen Sorry, I don't get it. After the manipulation, the DATA turned into data.frame, but image_read is for the image files, and image_data is for magick object. Simply throw the data.frame into the `image_read()` seemed not working.

Comment: Yes you need to convert it back into a matrix shape first, and then `image_read()`.

Comment: considering read_image also does not handle grayscale images very well, the easiest way is to do a `writePNG(matrix)` first